# Why would someone override paintEvent() just to drawPrimitive?

Tags: c++, qt4

What's the point of this paintEvent override:

```
void QWidgetDerivedWhatchamit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Surely that's what QWidget already does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ever need to do that if you derive from QWidget. Forget you ever saw that code :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two main reasons why someone would want to write this code.

1) They want to draw/write something or use an image in the background of the widget. In that case they have to implement the paintEvent method.

2) They want to leverage Qt Stylesheets such as setting a transparent background on the widget. Stylesheets work fine with built-in classes like QLabel or QPushButton. However, if someone creates her own class, derived from QWidget, Stylesheets don't work unless you reimplement paintEvent and write exactly those lines that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.  It could be a place-holder, ie. the developer intended to override it to add a new feature but didn't get around to it and left the above in.  Also, what is the default behavior for paintEvent in the base class?  Is it PE_Widget, or something else?

Comment: Well, I stepped into both the QWidget::paintEvent and the drawPrimitive functions.  Point of fact, neither one actually does anything at all.  There are cases when drawPrimitive(PE_Widget...) would do something, but not when `this` is derived directly from QWidget.  I guess the mystery as to why someone thought they should do this may remain a mystery.

Comment: @Noah What happens if you remove this event?

Comment: AFAICT, nothing at all changes.  At this point I guess I am no longer worried about what it's doing but more about why someone thought they should do this.  The code in question is from a qt-solutions library so I'd assume the authors have intimate knowledge of Qt...though the design of the lib is really quite terrible (IMNSHO) so maybe I'm mistaken.  Is there some historical reason?  A standard for possible future alterations?  It's pointless code and I'm always disturbed by such :p